# Con una función o void con un encabezado que contenga un puntero sin el "&", ¿es necesario crear un auxiliar del mismo tipo y eliminarlo al final?

Tags: c++, punteros

Si me dan una función o void en el que el encabezado tenga un puntero pasado por valor/copia (es decir sin el "&"), ¿es necesario crear un auxiliar del mismo tipo y eliminarlo al final?

Ejemplo:

```
srtuct nodo {
  int num
};

typdef nodo * ptr;

void example(ptr p) 
{
  ptr aux = p;
  ...
  delete(p);
}
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, requeriría más contexto para poder responderte.

Comment: Por cierto: ¿_typo_ en `struct` y `typedef`?

Answer (score 2):

Los punteros es necesario borrarlos cuando no se usan, así que la pregunta debería ser ¿Cómo saber, dentro de una función que recibe un puntero, si el puntero ya no es necesario?

Y la respuesta es: No lo puedes saber.

---

En C++ el uso de punteros en crudo está desaconsejado en la mayoría de casos y se considera una mala práctica, es fácil de ver por qué. El ejemplo que has puesto es uno de muchos que ilustran esa mala práctica.

Para saber qué hacer con memoria dinámica y cuándo hacerlo debe estar muy claro el concepto de posesión (*ownership*), debes poder responder estas preguntas:

- ¿Quién (dónde se) pidió esta memoria?
- ¿Para qué es necesaria?
- ¿Cuánto tiempo se necesita?

Si no puedes responder esas preguntas, no podrás saber qué hacer con un puntero que (potencialmente) apunta a memoria dinámica; veamos unos ejemplos:

```
void example(int *p) 
{
    // ...
    delete p;
}

int main()
{
    int *i = new int{42};
    int *v = new int[42]{};
    int *m = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int x;

    example(i);
    // No puedo cambiar el contenido de 'i' ya que fue borrado.
    *i = 0;

    // Borra el puntero con 'delete' pero debería borrarlo con 'delete[]'.
    example(v);

    // Borra el puntero con 'delete' pero debería borrarlo con 'free'.
    example(m);

    // Intenta borrar memoria que no se pidió dinámicamente.
    example(&x);

    return 0;
}
```

La función `example` no sabe que el puntero `i` se necesita después de la llamada, así que lo ha borrado e invalidado, tampoco sabe que el puntero `v` apunta a una formación de enteros así que ha usado el borrado incorrecto; lo mismo sucede con el puntero `m` y el peor caso se da con `x`, ya que intenta borrar una memoria que no se pidió dinámicamente.

Para evitar estos disparates, **NO** trabajes con punteros en crudo a no ser que tu código sea el responsable de esos punteros y tu código sepa perfectamente dónde son necesarios sus datos y durante cuanto tiempo.